# Swift shows old version even after installed a newer version

Tags: ios, swift

New to the iOS land.

I am using an old Mac with OS Catalina 10.15.7, XCode 12.4, Swift 5.3.2

I need to use the `async` function in my Swift project, checked and found that it is only supported since the Swift version 5.5.

So I downloaded the [Swift 5.5](https://download.swift.org/swift-5.5-branch/xcode/swift-5.5-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2021-12-07-a/swift-5.5-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2021-12-07-a-osx.pkg) from the [Swift Download page](https://www.swift.org/download/) and double clicked the pkg file to install it.

It showed the installer GUI and I installed it successfully.

Then I closed my terminal and re-opened it again and use this command to check the Swift version:

`xcrun swift -version`

But it still shows the old 5.3.2.

What steps did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that to use a different installed Swift version in XCode, do this:

1. Xcode (menu on the top bar)
2. Toolchains
3. Voila~ All my installed Swifts are here

So I have

- Xcode 12,4 (which has Swift 5.3.2)
- Swift 5.5 Development Snapshot
- Swift 5.6 Release 2022-03-08

Here is the article which helps me:
https://www.shawnbaek.com/posts/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-swift-on-xcode-12

Answer (score 0):

I think that your old Mac has not the requirements to run 5.5.

See here

https://developer.apple.com/de/support/xcode/

So the least possible Version is shown.

Comment: I was thinking so as well until I found the toolchains.

Comment: You can have different Toolchains but they have to be supported by your systems hardware/software etc. so I think this is the problem